# Can we automate kubectl commends

Tags: json, kubernetes, yaml

I am running below 4 statements one by one. is there any way to run these commands at a time in one shot if possible using parameters.

```
kubectl create namespace testnamsespace

kubectl create secret tls testnamsespace-ingress-tls --key $key --cert $crt --namespace=testnamsespace

helm install my-nginx-ingress-deslobarmtest stable/nginx-ingress --namespace testnamsespace --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP="<<publicIp>>"
```

And creating Ingress

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using either of the following approaches:

1. Put all these together in a shell script to run.

or else,

2. You can use any CI pipelines. Most of the CI pipelines supports parameterization and configurations. You can pass those values using the variable in your pipeline yml file as variable.